# Function definitions

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Section 6.9.1 in the C99 standard states the following:

```
function-definition:
  declaration-specifiers declarator declaration-list_opt compound-statement

declaration-list:
  declaration
  declaration-list declaration
```

On the other hand, Section 6.7.5 allows the declarator to be an array.

Does this mean that the C99 grammar (ignoring all the constraints) allows for something like this:

```
  int x[ 5 ] { return 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that the C99 grammar (ignoring all the constraints) allows for something like this:

Yes.

Comment: Can you provide an working example please

Comment: The example is in OPs question. I decided that if OP is asking for confirmation, there is nothing more for me to say. `restrict int a;` or `int a[0];` are also valid to grammar, but breaking "constraints".

Answer (score 1):

The very next sentence of C99 6.9.1:

> **Constraints**
> The identifier declared in a function definition (which is the name of the function) shall have a function type, as specified by the declarator portion of the function definition.

You cannot ignore constraints since they are mandatory and normative.

Comment: Thanks, so I will conclude that, if we ignore the constraints, the grammar allows for: 

```
  int x[ 5 ] { return 0; }
```

Comment: @BogdanTanasa What do you mean by "ignoring the constraints"? Aren't they part of the grammar?

Comment: In my point of view, the constraints should be in the grammar rules themselves. The C99 grammar allows for all constructs which need to be filter out from the point of view of constraints. In other words, ideally, a good grammar should not need constraints.

Comment: @Bob__: The grammar is the language specified by the lexical production rules alone, summarized in Annex A of the C standard.

Comment: @BogdanTanasa: It is not possible to specify the C language with the grammar alone, without constraints. For example, there is no way to specify purely grammatically that the constant expression giving the size of an array is non-zero.